# Does importing a module (but not using it) decrease performance in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, pdb

I'm running a website using Django, and I import ipdb at the beginning of almost all of my scripts to make debugging easier. However, most of the time I never use the functions from the module (only when I'm debugging).

Just wondering, will this decrease my performance? It's just that when I want to create a breakpoint I prefer to write:

```
ipdb.set_trace()
```

as opposed to:

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

But I've seen the second example done in several places, which makes me wonder if it's more efficient...

I just don't know how importing python modules relates to efficiency (assuming you're not using the module methods within your script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @wRAR mentioned, *Loading a module may imply executing any amounts of code which can take any amount of time*. On the other hand, the module will only be loaded once and any subsequent attempt to import will find the module present in `os.sys.modules` and reference to that.

In a Django environment in debuging mode, modules are removed from Django's [`AppCache`](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=lJwOcsZq5g4C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=django+AppCache&source=bl&ots=b1Mwli-jy3&sig=bboLpTq7lLQ8gtbWRkpbSIR8rEc&hl=pt-BR&ei=IiaLTubSDNHPgAfgnqmqAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=django%20AppCache&f=false) and actually re-imported only when they are changed, which you will probably not do with `ipdb`, so in your case it should not be an issue.

However, in cases it would be an issue, there are some ways around it. Suppose you have a custom module that you use to load anyway, you can add a function to it that imports `ipdb` only when you require it:

```
# much used module: mymodule
def set_trace():
    import ipdb
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

in the module you want to use `ipdb.set_trace`:

```
import mymodule

mymodule.set_trace()
```

or, on top of your module, use the cross-module `__debug__` variable:

```
if __debug__:
    from ipdp import set_trace
else:
    def set_trace(): return
```

Comment: Does importing a module (but not using it) decrease performance in Python? That is the question

Comment: Indeed @joaquin, I was already in the process of my above edit when you wrote your comment ;). Some might not agree, but this is also a great place to give some problem-solving-oriented advice to whom is interested in the question.

Comment: Thanks! And I appreciated the practical examples. =)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Not usually

Long answer:

It will take time to load the module. This may be noticeable if you are loading python off a network drive or other slow source. But if running directly off a hard drive you'll never notice.

As @wRar points out, importing a module can execute any amount of code. You can have whatever code you want executed at module startup. However, most modules avoid executing unreasonable amounts of code during startup. So that itself probably isn't a huge cause.

However, importing very large modules especially those that also result in importing a large number of c modules will take time.

So importing will take time, but only once per module imported. If you import modules at the top of your modules (as opposed to in functions) it only applies to startup time anyways. Basically, you aren't going to get much optimisation mileage out of avoiding importing modules.

Comment: @JBernardo: You're right, I've noticed it, and `scipy` is much slower yet, so I usually only import the functions I actually use (`from scipy import foo, bar, spam`)

Comment: Loading a module may imply executing any amounts of code which can take any amount of time.

Comment: @heltonbiker, does that help? Doesn't that still have to import scipy module?

Comment: I'd say the short answer should be "probably not" rather than "No"

Comment: @Winston: It worked for me, script runs more quickly, I think it has to do with compiling functions to bytecode. From what I've read, importing a module has to add all its content to current namespace, when importing specific functions would add just those functions to current namespace.

Comment: @heltonbiker, that only applies if you are doing `from x import *`, is that what you were doing?

Answer (score 0):

Importing a module but not using it decreases (the system) performance:

1. It takes time to import the module
2. Imported modules use up memory

While the first point makes your program slower to start, the second point might make ALL your programs slower, depending on the total amount of memory you have on your system.